# ROS launchfile only recognized when in the same folder as the launchfile

Tags: bash, ros

I can only run

```
 roslaunch launchfile.launch
```

when I am in the same folder as the file.
If i go back a folder and run

```
 roslaunch ~/<directory>/launchfile.launch
```

it says

```
RLException: [launchfile.launch] is not a launch file name
 The traceback for the exception was written to the log file
```

What is the issue? This exact same behaviour happens both in a script as well as if I type it into bash.

Comment: Yes, that was just an example showing where it does not work

Comment: The file needs to be in the sourced workspace directory `launch`.

Comment: @Fruchtzwerg, I kept it in the root of the catkin folder and it works just fine when I run the command from the same directory as the launchfile.. Could you clarify what you mean by sourced workspace directory. Where exactly should it go?

Answer (score 0):

The file needs to be in the sourced workspace directory launch. – Fruchtzwerg 10 hours ago

This was it. 
use echo $CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH to find the workspace directory and paste it there. That is it